# Monitoring Jobs Status in Flink Session Cluster (Flink 1.14)

Tags: apache-flink

I have a Flink Cluster running in Session mode. I was wondering if there's a way to monitor the jobs running on the cluster with any automated means such as prometheus metrics etc?

I would like to be notified when a job errors out or something goes wrong. Is it possible with the Session Mode cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You can send Flink metrics to Prometheus or another reporter (multiple reporters too). Read this [doc](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/metric_reporters/).

Read [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/ops/metrics/#metrics) how to produce metrics.

I don't think that metrics depends on deployment mode.

Comment: I don't see the required metrics being posted by Flink 1.14. I'm specifically looking for job related metrics than the cluster itself.

Comment: If you can't find predefined metrics you can always create metrics that you want.

Comment: Yeah, that's something I want to do. Any idea how to get started on that? Since ours is a session cluster, there are multiple jobs running on the cluster and would like to keep monitoring their status via such metrics.

Comment: I would recommend you to read the doc. I gave you the links in my answer. You can access the metric system from any user function that extends RichFunction. For ex: `.map(new YourMetricsClass())` Your `new YourMetricsClass()` should extend RichMapFunction